# Spring xml to resource.groovy

Tags: grails

I am doing configuration in `resource.groovy`. I am stuck on **'bean-method'** xml, how it will be set in  `resource.groovy` and how to pass arguments to the method.

XML config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="neo4j"></context:component-scan>
j

    <util:map id="config">
        <entry key="ha.server_id" value="1" />
        <entry key="ha.initial_hosts" value="127.0.0.1:5001,127.0.0.1:5002" />
        <!-- put in more config parameters here, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html -->
    </util:map>
    <bean id="graphDbFactory"
        class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory" />
    <bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory" factory-method="newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder">
        <constructor-arg value="/home/alok/Desktop/data1" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder"
        factory-method="setConfig">
        <constructor-arg ref="config" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
        factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"   base-package="neo4j"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="neo4j" />

</beans>
```

My `resource.groovy` is

```
beans = {

    xmlns neo4j:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    context.'component-scan'('base-package': 'neo4j')
    neo4j.'repositories'('base-package':'neo4j')
//      neo4j.'config'('storeDirectory':'target/db5', 'base-package':'neo4j')

    graphDbFactory(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory)

    graphDbBuilder=ref('graphDbFactory'){ 
        bean -> bean.factoryMethod='newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder'
         bean.constructorArgs=['/home/alok/Desktop/data1'] 
         }

println "after"

graphDbBuilderFinal=ref('graphDbBuilder'){ 
    bean -> bean.factoryMethod='setConfig'
    server_id= ["1"]
    initial_hosts= ["127.0.0.1:5001,127.0.0.1:5002"]
}

graphDatabaseService=ref('graphDbBuilderFinal'){
    bean -> bean.factoryMethod='newGraphDatabase'
}

neo4j.'config'('base-package':'neo4j')
}
```

I am getting error `bean name must not be empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory

beans = {

   xmlns neo4j:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
   xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   context.'component-scan'('base-package': 'neo4j')
   neo4j.'repositories'('base-package':'neo4j')
//   neo4j.'config'('storeDirectory':'target/db5', 'base-package':'neo4j')


   def config = ['ha.server_id': 1, 'ha.initial_hosts': '127.0.0.1:5001,127.0.0.1:5002']

   graphDbFactory(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory)

   graphDbBuilder(graphDbFactory: 'newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder') { bean ->
      bean.constructorArgs = ['/home/alok/Desktop/data1']
   }

   graphDbBuilderFinal(graphDbBuilder: 'setConfig') { bean ->
      bean.constructorArgs = [config]
   }

   graphDatabaseService(graphDbBuilderFinal: 'newGraphDatabase') { bean ->
      bean.destroyMethod = 'shutdown'
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but one exception i am facing there, No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined .

Comment: I think you are missing a configuration step that would have registered that for you. It should be easy enough to do, but you might have further issues. Add the import `import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate` and then the bean definition would be `neo4jTemplate(Neo4jTemplate, ref('graphDatabaseService'))`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for beans with a factory instead of a class is:

```
graphDbBuilder(graphDbFactory:"newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder") { bean ->
  bean.constructorArgs = ...
}
```

Bean definitions must be *method calls*, your version has an *assignment expression* outside a bean definition block, which is not allowed.